# better way to feed arguments to function

Tags: python, function, lambda

I need to take a function which accepts two arguments and pre-fill one of them so that I end up with a function which accepts one argument.

I'm currently doing this with:

```py
res_fn= lambda _res: pool_pad(_res, 32)
```

which works but is more complex and difficult to read than I'd like.

Is there a more elegant option or is what I have as good as it gets?

Comment: what do you mean by pre-fill? Default arguments?

Comment: If you define a function as `def function(paramater1, paramater2=="value):"` then paramater 2 is optional

Comment: are you trying to curry?

Comment: @ Jammy Dodger. There is no default argument. Each call of `pool_pad` takes a specific int value so a default value would only fix the problem in one of multiple places.

Comment: I was a little light on details so as explanation: `res_fn` is used as an argument to another function. It allows me to define behavior in the function call rather than having multiple flags and multiple `if: else:` checks in the function body.

Comment: If you're familiar with residual neural networks; res_fn defines what to do with the residual. In most cases it will be the same as input but during scale transitions it needs to be resized. This can be done with a pooling layer and a padding layer, or a convolution layer with stride>1, or a concatenation of segments of the input, etc. Using a function as an argument I can get any behavior I like in a very clean very up-gradable way. I just didn't want the function call to get too long in the process. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functools is here for that purpose:

```
from functools import partial
def pool_pad(x,y):
    return x+y
res_fn = partial(pool_pad, y=2)
res_fn(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
res_fn = functools.partial(pool_pad, second_arg=32)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
def res_fn(_res):
    return pool_pad(_res, 32)
```